# Indication of when a minor rev level will increase after an OS patch

Tags: linux, redhat, patch

The question came up asking how a person would know if a minor rev level of a OS patch for Redhat would be known ahead of a patch. As an example, if a server is at RHEL 6.6 what would indicate that after a yum update was done the OS would be RHEL 6.7? Is there a package that would indicate if the minor version number would bump up?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be better asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) but yes you should have a package called `redhat-release` or in my case `centos-release` which gives the current version information.

`rpm -q centos-release returns centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`

Comment: Well, duh. I've seen the package enough times but figured it couldn't be as simple as that. Thanks for the cluegram.

Comment: :) no problem. Sometimes the obvious things get overlooked. You can accept the answer by clicking the tick - It's possible this post may get migrated/closed at some point once its been through the review queue just in case it vanishes.